# Post-order Traverse in PowerShell recurse

Tags: powershell

Get-ChildItem -Recurse in powershell currently traverse a directory in level order fashion. Is there any way to traverse a directory in post-order way in Powershell?

I am trying to delete files which are older than certain times. and after deleting files, if subfolder is empty, delete that folder too. Right now am doing this.

```
$path = 'D:\Files'
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object {
(($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)) -and ($_ -is [system.io.fileinfo]) )
} | Remove-Item 


Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object {
($_ -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]) -and $_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) -and ((Get-ChildItem $_.FullName).Count -eq 0)
} | Remove-Item -Force
```

But I want to do it in a single command. Not as two different command.

Comment: Please _edit the question_ and explain with more details what you are trying to do. A practical example, even in pseudocode, would be nice.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve that would benefit from some other sequence?

Comment: Do you actually want to lookup the items in reverse order, or is simply re-sorting them after a regular `get-childitem` an option?

Comment: Question has been updated.

Comment: As an aside: in PSv3+ you can limit enumeration to files and directories with `-File` and `-Directory`, respectively. In an enumeration that comprises both types, `$_.PSIsContainer` can be used to identify directories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could reverse the order of the items returned by `Get-ChildItem` with `[Array]::Reverse`

Full script:

```
$items = Get-ChildItem 'D:\Files' -Recurse
[Array]::Reverse($items)
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
foreach ($item in $items) {
    if ($item.PSIsContainer) {
        if ($item.CreationTime -lt $date -and (Get-ChildItem $item.FullName).Count -eq 0) {
            Remove-Item $item.FullName
        }
    }
    elseif ($item.LastWriteTime -lt $date) {
        Remove-Item $item.FullName
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be great if Get-ChildItem would support -DepthFirst, -Postorder o similar.

Comment: This definitely doesn't work for me - it should be the children, then the immediate parent, but for me the parent returns later in the collection.

Comment: @user7660047 But that's also how `Get-ChildItem` works. It will list all immediate children first, and *then* continue with the next deepest level. If you want it different, you could easily write your own recursive function for that.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the post order working properly with GCI, someone claimed it should, but it wasn't traversing depth first. Below is a naive implementation of the classic post order algorithm using the push directory and pop directory commands. Put your "actions" where Write-Host is.

```
function PostOrder($d){
  pushd $d
  $folders = Get-ChildItem .\ -Directory -Force
  foreach ($folder in $folders){
    PostOrder($folder)
  }
  popd 
  Write-Host $d.FullName
}

PostOrder("C:\myFolder")
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.